# How to unmount react-live-clock

Tags: reactjs, react-router

i used this (react-live-clock) component inside my home.js component of App.js, but when i change route, react throws and error about react update of unmount component.
to solve it i tried using useEffect hook:

```
const [timeclock , settimeclock] = useState([]); 

    useEffect(() => {
        time();

},[]);
const time = async ()=> {

    const data =  (<Clock  format={'HH:mm:ss A'} ticking={true} timezone={'America/Toronto'} />)

    settimeclock(data);

}
```

but still this throws error: [As shown in picture below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oT5kB.png)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it was a bug in the library, s. https://github.com/pvoznyuk/react-live-clock/commit/ab59798a47c1c546e4fffe8f57508b6754fe3b05 .

I've used 5.0.0-beta4 successfully without any changes to my code, but it required adding `"react-moment": "^0.9.7",` and `"moment-timezone": "^0.5.31",` to the package dependencies manually.